# Evaluation of checkBoxesFieldList in Yesod

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

I'm struggling with the evaluation of `checkBoxesFieldList` of monadic forms in my Yesod appliction.

I'm using these to create `n`-questions where `n` is the number of `checkBoxesFieldList`, with 4 answers (only `True`/`False`) each. But in comparison to the applicative forms, these already "evaluate" the result and tell me if I answered correctly.

The problem occurs if there are boxes unchecked, or you check a wrong one out of four, so I can't know what wrong answer you checked.

Example:

- If I checked only the first box, the result is `[False]`.
- If I checked only the second box wrong, the result is still `[False]`.
- If I checked only the third box (but it was the right answer), the result is [True].

What I want to achieve: The result from `runFormPost` should give me a `[Bool]` based on: `checked -> return True`, `unchecked -> return False`.

Example:

If I checked only the first box wrong, the result should be `[True, False, False, False]`

I already had to customize the `checkboxesField` from the library, but I just can't find a way remove the evaluation.

Here is the code:

```
data Question = Question {
   , identity   :: Text
   , content    :: Text
   , answerList :: [Answer]
   , maxScore   :: Int
  }

data Answer = Answer {
   , identity  :: Text
   , content   :: Text
   , isCorrect :: Bool
   , hint      :: Text
  }

zipAnswers :: [Answer] -> [(Text, Bool)]
zipAnswers [] = []
zipAnswers ((Answer _ text val _):xs) = (text, val):zipAnswers xs

listEditMForm :: [Question] -> Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult ([FormResult (Maybe [Bool])]), Widget)
listEditMForm xs token = do
      check_fields <- forM xs (\(Question _ content alist _ ) -> mopt (checkboxesFieldList' $ zipAnswers alist) (fromString $ T.unpack content) Nothing)
      let (check_results, check_views) = unzip check_fields
      let numerated_views = zip ([1..]::[Int]) check_views
      let widget = [whamlet|
              ^{token}
                <ul class="tabs">
                   $forall (c,view) <- numerated_views
                       <li>
                           <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab#{fvId view}">
                           <label for="tab#{fvId view}">Q #{show c}
                           <div id="tab-content#{fvId view}" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
                             <p class=boldWhite> #{fvLabel view}: </p>
                             ^{fvInput view}
                             <br>
             <input class=button type=submit value="Testing">
        |]
      return ((FormSuccess check_results), widget)




checkboxesFieldList' :: (Eq a, RenderMessage site FormMessage, RenderMessage site msg) => [(msg, a)]
                     -> Field (HandlerT site IO) [a]
checkboxesFieldList' = checkboxesField' . optionsPairs



checkboxesField' :: (Eq a, RenderMessage site FormMessage)
                 => HandlerT site IO (OptionList a)
                 -> Field (HandlerT site IO) [a]
checkboxesField' ioptlist = (multiSelectField ioptlist)
    { fieldView =
        \theId name attrs val _ -> do
            opts <- fmap olOptions $ handlerToWidget ioptlist
            let optselected (Left _) _ = False
                optselected (Right vals) opt = (optionInternalValue opt) `elem` vals
            [whamlet|
                  <span ##{theId}>
                    $forall opt <- opts
                        <label>
                          <input type=checkbox name=#{name} value=#{optionExternalValue opt} *{attrs} :optselected val opt:checked>
                          <span class=simpleWhite> #{optionDisplay opt}
                |]
    }
```